# What exactly is a single Heroku Web Dyno?

Tags: heroku, amazon-web-services

According to [Why do people use Heroku when AWS is present? What distinguishes Heroku from AWS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9802259/why-do-people-use-heroku-when-aws-is-present-whats-distinguishing-about-heroku), it seems that several Heroku Web Dynos run on a single Amazon EC2 CPU.

How many Dynos run on one CPU? What are the specs?

Do a large number of Dynos running on one CPU affect the other Dynos?

Comment: They are kinda fuzzy about them...

Comment: It's worth to say that Heroku routing mesh is not so intelligent, it distributes requests RANDOMLY across your dynos. In cases where there are a large number of dynos, the algorithm MAY optionally bias its selection towards dynos resident in the same AWS availability zone as the router making the selection.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

When you deploy a Heroku application, you build a virtual machine image called a `slug` using one or more `buildpacks`.  When a virtual machine instance is launched from this `slug`, it's called a `dyno`.

Each `dyno` runs a single process inside your application virtual machine.  Heroku does not officially describe how dynos are provisioned, but anecdotal analysis shows many dynos are run on a single Amazon `XL` EC2 instance, sharing disk, CPU, and memory across all dynos.  There are definitely "noisy neighbors" when sharing resources, but direct data or stats are not provided. I can only share my anecdotal experience that this does indeed happen.

Each dyno is isolated within the EC2 hosting machine, but shares the underlying resources.  This is similar to how `docker` and other application containers work.

Dynos are registered with the Heroku Routing Mesh, an intelligent load balancer that maps incoming web traffic to the application dyno.  Each dyno has a TCP port assigned that's registered with the routing mesh.

Heroku is a higher-level service on top of Amazon EC2.  They implement deployment, provisioning, monitoring, availability, and auto-scaling at a premium cost to raw EC2 hosting.  You can run your own EC2 instances, but need to implement those services yourself.

**Disclaimer:** I am not a Heroku employee and have no special knowledge of Heroku other than as a user of a large, high traffic Rails app.

**UPDATE:** Heroku launched `PX` size dynos this morning, which are hosted on a dedicated EC2 `c1.xlarge` instance, which solves all of the issues of noisy neighbors and resource contention I alluded to above.  At a heft price tag.  Details here: https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2014/2/3/heroku-xl

Comment: Well its a "dedicated" ec2 instance which itself is shared so there is still the issue of noisy neighbors.  Before it was more of a noisy roommate with noisy neighbors :)

Comment: Some dynos are on a shared underlying EC2 instance, some (PX class) dynos are on dedicated EC2 instances.

Comment: Agreed, but what I mean is the 'dedicated' ec2 instance is on a shared server, it isn't a dedicated server with a single instance on it so the concept of a 'noisy neighbor' is still present.

Comment: Yes, virtual machines all the way down.

Comment: What do you mean by virtual machine image? What is a buildpack?